# Suspend/Resume Issue

Tags: release-juno, greeter, graphic-drivers, suspend, xorg

I have a mid 2010 Macbook with the Nvidia GeForce 320m. Getting elementary to boot, and subsequently work well with this graphics card has required several adjustments, but I've gotten to a pretty stable place where I can run the Nvidia 340 graphics driver for simple gaming/graphics and resolution of overheating issues.

My issue though, is that suspending and subsequently resuming doesn't seem to work. I did not have this issue with the open-source drivers. After suspending, when I try to use the computer again, the screen is completely black and doesn't even have a backlight. I've noticed that Ubuntu has no trouble resuming however, so I installed GDM3 and found that I can resume okay using GDM3 as my display manager.

My question is: is there something I can do to make resuming function okay with LightDM? I imagine this is an Xorg config issue, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install the nvidia drivers?

Comment: Hi Maccer--I've installed them through both apt install and through the app center. The drivers seem to be working well overall, but I had to add a boot script to grub to make it set the display related pci channels as the masters.

Comment: I have the same problem with my 2010 MacBook Pro. Did you get it working with lightdm?